# How can I configure Google document so that table of content is automatically updated?

Tags: google-docs

How can I configure Google document so that table of content is automatically updated whenever a new heading is added?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Add a title, heading, or table of contents in a document](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/116338?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop), to update the table of content, the corresponding refresh button should be clicked.

It's worth to say that according to [comment #7](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2502#c7) on [Issue 2502: Add the ability to generate and update the TOC of a doc](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2502) it's not possible to create or update a Table of Content by using Google Apps Script.